# Is there an equivalent term for 'verbatim' in the context of images?

Tags: phrase-requests

When reproducing an excerpt from a text identically (and properly referenced), we are quoting it 'verbatim'. Is there an equivalent term in English that refers to reproducing an image faithfully? I would like to use a construction along the lines of: 'His reluctance to quote his own artwork [MISSING WORD]...'

Comment: Unretouched? @cobaltduck '*Re*' is a prefix, as is '*Un*', surely the correct word would therefore be [Untouched](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/untouched?q=Untouched)?

Comment: @MaverickJones- Except that the "base" term for altering a photograph (via airbrush or photoshop for example) is not touched, it is retouched.  So to say not retouched, we need unretouched.  Here are a [couple](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unretouched) [additional](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unretouched) references.

Comment: It seems like the meaning of *verbatim* can be extended to images. Example: ["You can therefore make verbatim copies of this image and use it in a similar way to Wikipedia."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Verbatim_copying_under_the_GFDL#Making_verbatim_copies_of_images)

Comment: @MavericjJones double prefixes aren't unknown. A related example: *unreproducible*; but also the famous *antidisestablishmentarianism*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the use of the word "*quote*" in reference to artwork (images).

You do not "*quote*" artwork; you "*copy*" it. You could maybe "*reuse*" it.

I suggest this construction:

> "His reluctance to **[copy/reuse]** his own artwork..."

Comment: This is all correct, but it does not attempt to answer the actual original question.

Comment: @cobaltduck That's true because the original question does not make sense.

Comment: Or "reproduce" though probably not in all contexts.

Answer (score 1):

In the world of photography, a piece can be [retouched](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retouch) (M-W link), meaning "to make small changes ... in order to improve the way it looks."  When all photography was done using silver-halide on gelatin, the manner of doing this was an [airbrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_manipulation) (Wikipedia link).  In digital photography we can use software to do retouching, such as the common PhotoShop.

Apparently, the term *retouched* can also be applied to paintings.  An article describing a famous example of [a botched restoration](http://latino.foxnews.com/latino/lifestyle/2012/08/24/in-botched-restoration-project-jesus-christ-becomes-disfigured/) (FoxNews link) makes use of the term.

So, to describe an image which has not been altered or improved in anyway, the term is [unretouched](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unretouched) (Collins link).

In your example, and borrowing from a previous answer, I would phrase like so:

> His reluctance to use unretouched copies of his own artwork...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word "precisely" in  place of verbatim. Meaning exactly as the artwork was originally designed, just like verbatim would mean exactly as the words were spoken.

Answer (score 0):

He is reluctant to transfer his previous [art] work *unadulterated*, or *as is*, or *without variation*, or *without any reworking*, or *in its original form*, or *as a carbon copy*.